# fatal error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory when compiling wine, but the file exists

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, cross-compiling, wine

Following [this documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine#Shared_WoW64) i had attempted to compile wine with --enable-win64 , however i was met with 4 errors all complaining about "stdarg.h" not existing :

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.3-win32/include/stdarg.h:1:15: fatal
> error: stdarg.h: No such file or directory
> 1 | #include_next <stdarg.h>

I checked with a file explorer and sure enough it does exist, so what gives? I have googled this error to the ends of the earth but i cannot find any instance of anyone having this issue while attempting to compile wine.

If additional information is needed i will be happy to provide it, the full log is [here](https://hastebin.com/raw/gigijuyelu)

EDIT: Going off of Gerhardh and WENDYN's comments, the issue seems to be linked to the first line of stdarg.h which is "#include_next <stdarg.h>", which apparently includes the next file with the same header name, and i most likely am missing that "next" header.

Completely shooting in the dark but i commented out #include_next <stdarg.h> on the first line of the file, it **seems** to have compiled fine, tomorrow i will use the build extensively to see if any problems arise, however i would not call this a solution as i had to edit the header with root and this could potentially cause issues with the system.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the error message or relevant part into the question.

Comment: It's worth to mention that the error messages actually come from within `stdarg.h` where it want to `#include_next <stdarg.h>`.

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Wrapper-Headers.html).